# I can't see how this is giving me a nullref exception

Tags: vb.net, nullreferenceexception

Why does the code pasted below throw me a Null Reference Exception? Because I simply can't seem to find out why.

Note: The textboxes have the correct names & they aren't empty when I get the exception.

My code: (I've highlighted the line with the error)

```
txtGuid.BackColor = Color.White
    txtName.BackColor = Color.White
    If txtGuid.Text <> "" And txtName.Text <> "" Then
        Dim name As String = txtName.Text
        Dim guid As String = txtGuid.Text
        **frmWhitelist.names.Add(name)**
        frmWhitelist.guids.Add(guid)
        Me.Close()
    Else
        If txtGuid.Text = "" Then
            txtGuid.BackColor = Color.Red
        End If
        If txtName.Text = "" Then
            txtName.BackColor = Color.Red
        End If
        lblError.Text = "Please check your input in the red-colored fields."
    End If
```

Call stack:

`> DayZAdminApp.exe!DayZAdminApp.inptBoxWhitelist.btnOk_Click(Object sender, System.EventArgs e) Line 15 + 0x3d bytes  Basic`

While debugging, the `txtGuid.text` and `txtName.text` both have text values in my Locals tab.

PS: If this is caused by the fact that I'm trying 2 add items to a public var on another form, how can I work around this?

PPS: The `frmWhitelist.names`and `frmWhitelist.guids` are declared as such:

`Public names, guids As List(Of String)`

Comment: Could you tell us which one has the NullReferenceException? You can easily check this with the debugger attached

Comment: `frmWhitelist.names.Add(name)` <- that line.

Comment: I guess then frmWhitelist or the names-collection of it are null is null. Where does it get created?

Comment: It's called from a button, that form works just fine & that's the form which calls the form with this code. (I'm sort of using it as a custom inputbox with 2 inputs)

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lists are `Nothing` since you haven't initialized them.

So you get an exception here:

```
frmWhitelist.names
```

This avoids the exception:

```
Public names As New List(Of String)
Public guids As New List(Of String)
```

You are just declaring them here:

```
Public names, guids As List(Of String)
```

They are still `Nothing` at this point even if they are declared.

Comment: Right, I'm an idiot, I knew I should've done that, but I couldn't remember why, thanks :)

Comment: You still need to assign them to the names collection: frmWhitelist.names = names
frmWhitelist.guids = guids

Comment: @Kenneth: I don't understand. Both lists are declared in a different form. OP wants to add strings here `frmWhitelist.names.Add(name)`.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I thought he had declared them locally. If he has declared them as auto-properties in the other form then he should be fine.